# Is there any way to get data by joining two boxes in hive db flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am looking for something which would help me fetch data from two different boxes and join them as we do in traditional databases.

for an example i have two different boxes namely:

`Hive.box<Student>, Hive.box<Results>`

now i want to fetch data from these two boxes and save them to Hive.box.
is this a feasible way or is there any other way to do this?